# Inserting big BLOB takes long time

Tags: .net, sql-server, blob, sqlcommand

I am building a complex application. Part from that application is an agent which runs on other servers and sends data to a web service (ASP MVC)-> JSON.
In the Controller i am converting the data to XML and call a stored procedure which stores it in a table. A SQL agent job picks up the data and performs the necessary create, update & delete operations against some tables.

So far so good...

The problem here is the speed. The generated XML has a size of multiple MBs. Currently its ~16MB. Inserting the XML string into a new DB row takes 5-6 seconds.

What i tried:

- Changed the DB column to XML. Same result!
- I thought the problem is Entity Framework. I replaced that code with a Stored procedure. Same result!
- Removed all statement from the SP -> empty stored procedure. Same result!
- Changed the parameter type from string/nvarchar(max) to byte[]/varbinary(max). This brought some improvement. It's now 50% faster. But still slow.

It seems that passing this big string or byte array to the SQL server takes very long!

What can i do to get this faster?

I thought about the following:
- Place the data on the file system and instruct the SQL server to process it using SELECT FROM OPENROWSET.

Are there any alternatives?

Comment: What is the definition of the table? Are you storing as text or using SQL Server's XML support to parse it?

Comment: You can store the data on disk and have a file pointer/path in the database. In most situations this is a better approach. It keeps your database smaller, less fragmentation, better performance, easier to persist changes to the data. I am sure there are articles out there on the pros of keeping (larger) blobs out of the database.

Comment: This might be of interest to you: [Programmers Stackexchange - Is it a bad practice to store large files in a database?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/150787) in particular the 2nd answer about `FILESTREAM` if you wish to forge ahead.

Comment: @Igor Agree. That would mean that the server has to host both, the web and the SQL server. I also thought about to include the storage on the filesystem in the transaction using TransactionScope an the NTFS transactional features.

Comment: @Richard I tried both. But it doesn't matter. It's the "marshalling" the big data to the SQL parameter that takes time in my case...

Comment: Did you check out the [FileStream](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993(v=sql.105).aspx) feature? This would give you the best of both worlds. Files stored on disk but pointer in the database and all managed under the umbrella of Sql Server AND it seems that it should be able to deliver on performance although you would have to test that.

Comment: @Igor Yes i did. It's somewhat faster. I think i go with the approach i explained earlier: TransactionScope and the transacted versions of the Win32 file functions like "CreateFileTransacted" etc... this allows me to have fast file I/O and consistency as well

Answer (score 0):

Try to run your SQL operation asynchronously. I hope you don't need immediate result.

```
Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new Threading.WaitCallback(InsertBLOB), MyBLOB);
```

The disadvantage of this approach is that you won't receive errors at runtime.